# Get authenticated user from ASP.NET in ASP classic

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp-classic

I have a lot of ASP.NET 2.0 applications using the form authentication. It works well but now I need to integrate this in one of our old ASP classic application. I've checked this Scott Gu blog entry (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/04/tip-trick-integrating-asp-net-security-with-classic-asp-and-non-asp-net-urls.aspx) and I follow the instruction but it doesn't work for me. When I check the AUTH_USER server variable in my asp.net page, it contains the same user name as User.Identity.Name but the same server variable is empty when I return to my ASP classic page. All pages are in the same virtual directory on IIS 6.0.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what was missing (the wildcard configuration). With that set properly, it works.

Comment: Hi, any chance you could expand on this? I have the same problem and was wondering how you came across your solution?